# Klaviyo Form shows twice on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, jinja2, shopify, shopify-template

I embedded a klaviyo form on shopify and it showed twice on the homepage of the shop I'm working on. I'm quite new to shopify development but know django and a little rails but still get confused on reading codes.

```
<div class="homepage-page {{ section.settings.homepage_page_color }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="index-page">
    <!-- form -->
  <div id="shopify-section-1538847772051" class="shopify-section adjust--white">
  <div class="klaviyo-form-LLvHeC"></div> 
  </div>
  {% for block in section.blocks %}
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="grid">

    {% case block.type %}
      {% when 'page' %}
        {% if block.settings.home_page_content != blank %}
          {% assign page = pages[block.settings.home_page_content] %}
          {% assign page_src = page.content | escape %}
          {% if page_src contains '&lt;img' %}
            {% assign homepage_page_grid = 'one-whole' %}
          {% else %}
            {% assign homepage_page_grid = 'large--five-sixths push--large--one-twelfth' %}
          {% endif %}
          <div class="grid__item {{ homepage_page_grid }}">
            {% if block.settings.home_page_show_title %}
              <h4 class="home__subtitle">{{ page.title }}</h4>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="rte homepage-page__content">
              {% unless page == blank or page.empty? %}
                {{ page.content }}
              {% else %}
                {{ 'home_page.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
              {% endunless %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% when 'text' %}
        <div class="grid__item large--five-sixths push--large--one-twelfth">
          <div class="rte homepage-page__content">
            {% if block.settings.home_page_richtext != blank %}
              {{ block.settings.home_page_richtext }}
            {% else %}
              {{ 'home_page.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      {% else %}
    {% endcase %}
  </div>
</div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% if section.blocks.size == 0 %} 
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <div class="rte homepage-page__content">
        {{ 'home_page.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% schema %}
```

Which part of this piece of code is the one showing the second form?

[image]

**This is the form on top**

[image]

**This is the form that I do not need which is near the footer**

Answer (score 1):

You have not added the full code for the section, but as you are adding it on homepage I am sure it is a dynamic section. You can read more about Sections and their types on Shopify Docs about [Theme Sections](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections#static-and-dynamic-sections).

In you particular scenario, it looks like you are using 2 different instances of same type of section. So for 2 instances, your section code is included and rendered twice, thus the multiple forms.

I don't know the exact use case, but you can fix it by adding another block type specifically for adding klaviyo form code or moving klaviyo form code in some other file included on homepage.

This code is included anytime that you are using that type of section. If you add another section of that type , you would see 3 forms.

```
  <div id="shopify-section-1538847772051" class="shopify-section adjust--white">
  <div class="klaviyo-form-LLvHeC"></div> 
  </div>
```

The solution is to move this code outside of the section, like in some code snippet or add it as a separate block so that it is only rendered where added.